# How to insert text in a li with an array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm creating a site with many list and I have a structure like this:

```
<ul class="list-container">
  <li>TEXT
  <li>TEXT
  <li>TEXT
</ul>
```

Can I create an array like `var a = [1,2,3,4]` and `li` becomes:

```
<ul>
  <li>1
  <li>2
  <li>3
  <li>4
</ul>
```

I tried with:

```js
var a = [
  "Testo 1",
  "Testo 2",
  "Testo 3",
  "Testo 4"
];

for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelector("li").length; i++) {
  document.querySelector("li")[i].innerHTML = a[i];
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
  <li>
  <li>
</ul>
```

It doesn't work, Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `querySelector()` method only returns the first element that matches the specified selectors. To return all the matches, use the `querySelectorAll()` method instead.

```js
var a = [
  "Testo 1",
  "Testo 2",
  "Testo 3",
  "Testo 4"
];
for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll("li").length; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll("li")[i].innerHTML = a[i];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
  <li>
  <li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Can I ask you why with document.querySelector() doesn't work?

Comment: @Blind , use querySelectorAll no querySelector. check my updated answer again.

Answer (score 1):

In case you dont want to hard-code your `<li>` elements you can create them dynamically. You can also use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var a = [
    "Testo 1",
    "Testo 2",
    "Testo 3",
    "Testo 4"
];

a.map(function (el) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(el));
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li)
});
```

```html
<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

**Side Note:**

`<li>` elements should have a closing tag

Answer (score 1):

Soemthing like this in pure `JavaScript`:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var list = document.getElementById('list');
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
  var item = document.createElement('li');
  var text = document.createTextNode(arr[i]);
  item.appendChild(text);
  list.appendChild(item);
}
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```